# PHPExcel German vowels

Tags: php, phpexcel

I want to export a .xls-file from a database using phpexcel.
It works fine, however german vowels do make a lot of trouble.
Here is my code:

```html
 <?php
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Rome');

/***** EDIT BELOW LINES *****/
$DB_Server = "localhost"; // MySQL Server
$DB_Username = "user"; // MySQL Username
$DB_Password = "passw"; // MySQL Password
$DB_DBName = "test2015"; // MySQL Database Name
$xls_filename = 'export_'.date('Y-m-d').'.xls'; // Define Excel (.xls) file name





/***** DO NOT EDIT BELOW LINES *****/
// Create MySQL connection
$sql = "select * from Teilnehmer join mannschaften mann ON mann.M_id = Teilnehmer.Team";
$Connect = @mysql_connect($DB_Server, $DB_Username, $DB_Password) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL:<br />" . mysql_error() . "<br />" . mysql_errno());
// Select database
$Db = @mysql_select_db($DB_DBName, $Connect) or die("Failed to select database:<br />" . mysql_error(). "<br />" . mysql_errno());
// Execute query
$result = @mysql_query($sql,$Connect) or die("Failed to execute query:<br />" . mysql_error(). "<br />" . mysql_errno());



/** Error reporting */
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);

if (PHP_SAPI == 'cli')
        die('This example should only be run from a Web Browser');

/** Include PHPExcel */
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/Classes/PHPExcel.php';


// Create new PHPExcel object
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

// Set document properties
$objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setCreator("Piok")
->setLastModifiedBy("PIOK")
->setTitle("Piok")
->setSubject("Piok")
->setDescription("Piok")
->setKeywords("Piok")
->setCategory("Piok");


// Add some data
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
->setCellValue('A1', 'Vorname')
->setCellValue('B1', 'Nachname')
->setCellValue('C1', 'Jahrgang')
->setCellValue('D1', 'Geschlecht')
->setCellValue('E1', 'Email')
->setCellValue('F1', 'FISICODE')
->setCellValue('G1', 'Mannschaft');


$startzeile = 2;
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
{
        $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
        ->setCellValue('A'.$startzeile , $row[1])
        ->setCellValue('B'.$startzeile , $row[2])
        ->setCellValue('C'.$startzeile , $row[3])
        ->setCellValue('D'.$startzeile , $row[4])
        ->setCellValue('E'.$startzeile , $row[6])
        ->setCellValue('F'.$startzeile , $row[7])
        ->setCellValue('G'.$startzeile , $row[9]);

        $startzeile++;
}

// Rename worksheet
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle($xls_filename);


// Set active sheet index to the first sheet, so Excel opens this as the first sheet
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);


// Redirect output to a client’s web browser (Excel5)
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=utf-8');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="'.$xls_filename.'"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
// If you're serving to IE 9, then the following may be needed
header('Cache-Control: max-age=1');

// If you're serving to IE over SSL, then the following may be needed
header ('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT'); // Date in the past
header ('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s').' GMT'); // always modified
header ('Cache-Control: cache, must-revalidate'); // HTTP/1.1
header ('Pragma: public'); // HTTP/1.0

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
$objWriter->save('php://output');

exit;
?>
```

I use PHP 5.5
PHP-File encoding is set to UTF-8.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: The encoding in the file might be UTF-8, but what about your database connection? Is the collation of the database/table/column set correctly (utf8mb4_*_ci or utf8_*_ci)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problems like this are usually a result of using a wrong encoding in one of the ways to get the Data from one medium to the other.

Your Excel Output sets the Charset to utf-8, which is the normal thing to do. Now you should check what encoding you use in your database and make sure it is UTF-8 as well.

And as a last step make sure you "talk" in UTF-8 to the database as well.

```
mysql_set_charset("UTF8", $Connect);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try after clear output buffer.
Following answer will helpful for you. It's work for me.

```html
 <?php
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Rome');

/***** EDIT BELOW LINES *****/
$DB_Server = "localhost"; // MySQL Server
$DB_Username = "user"; // MySQL Username
$DB_Password = "passw"; // MySQL Password
$DB_DBName = "test2015"; // MySQL Database Name
$xls_filename = 'export_'.date('Y-m-d').'.xls'; // Define Excel (.xls) file name





/***** DO NOT EDIT BELOW LINES *****/
// Create MySQL connection
$sql = "select * from Teilnehmer join mannschaften mann ON mann.M_id = Teilnehmer.Team";
$Connect = @mysql_connect($DB_Server, $DB_Username, $DB_Password) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL:<br />" . mysql_error() . "<br />" . mysql_errno());
// Select database
$Db = @mysql_select_db($DB_DBName, $Connect) or die("Failed to select database:<br />" . mysql_error(). "<br />" . mysql_errno());
// Execute query
$result = @mysql_query($sql,$Connect) or die("Failed to execute query:<br />" . mysql_error(). "<br />" . mysql_errno());



/** Error reporting */
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);

if (PHP_SAPI == 'cli')
        die('This example should only be run from a Web Browser');

/** Include PHPExcel */
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/Classes/PHPExcel.php';


//clean output buffer previously
ob_end_clean();

//start output buffer
ob_start();

// Create new PHPExcel object
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

// Set document properties
$objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setCreator("Piok")
->setLastModifiedBy("PIOK")
->setTitle("Piok")
->setSubject("Piok")
->setDescription("Piok")
->setKeywords("Piok")
->setCategory("Piok");


// Add some data
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
->setCellValue('A1', 'Vorname')
->setCellValue('B1', 'Nachname')
->setCellValue('C1', 'Jahrgang')
->setCellValue('D1', 'Geschlecht')
->setCellValue('E1', 'Email')
->setCellValue('F1', 'FISICODE')
->setCellValue('G1', 'Mannschaft');


$startzeile = 2;
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
{
        $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
        ->setCellValue('A'.$startzeile , $row[1])
        ->setCellValue('B'.$startzeile , $row[2])
        ->setCellValue('C'.$startzeile , $row[3])
        ->setCellValue('D'.$startzeile , $row[4])
        ->setCellValue('E'.$startzeile , $row[6])
        ->setCellValue('F'.$startzeile , $row[7])
        ->setCellValue('G'.$startzeile , $row[9]);

        $startzeile++;
}

// Rename worksheet
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle($xls_filename);


// Set active sheet index to the first sheet, so Excel opens this as the first sheet
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);


// Redirect output to a client’s web browser (Excel5)
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=utf-8');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="'.$xls_filename.'"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
// If you're serving to IE 9, then the following may be needed
header('Cache-Control: max-age=1');

// If you're serving to IE over SSL, then the following may be needed
header ('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT'); // Date in the past
header ('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s').' GMT'); // always modified
header ('Cache-Control: cache, must-revalidate'); // HTTP/1.1
header ('Pragma: public'); // HTTP/1.0

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
$objWriter->save('php://output');

//Cleaning the ouput buffer
ob_flush();
exit;
?>
```